# Performance issues with Pentaho 5.0 + Mysql. Is vertica good option?

Tags: mysql, pentaho, vertica

We are using:

Pentaho (CE) 5.0. Server RAM: 30 GB. Server Core: 24
Mysql 5.1. with RAM 33 GB.

This has just one Cube's star schema which has a fact table with 10M rows(Total db size ~2GB). Analysis on single dimension runs into ~30 sec and it increases rapidly as we run into 2-3 cross join of dimensions. We figured that problem is with Mysql temp table creation which takes forever to return results.

So we are thinking of trying out Vertica (CE). 
In pentaho 5.0 (CE) user console, I see options to connect to various DBs(mysql, oracle etc) but vertica is not in that list. 
1. How can I make Pentaho connect to star schema created in Vertica?
2. Does Pentaho know to create Vertica-compatible queries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho does connect to Vertica ! just make sure you configure the drivers correctly !
As for the performance part ! Vertica will handle any query you have in less time then you think off !! 
 I suggest you give it a try !! I connecting with Pentaho is hard or you cannot try Talend (open source ETL tool).

And for articles on how to install and manage your Vertica cluster follow this [link](http://www.aodba.com/main_articles_single.php?art=9999&page=vertica&id_tit=6) .
And for info on how pentaho connects do vertica check this link